# Using 'LIKE' in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I am having trouble getting values in my laravel code. See here and notice   `->where('created_at', 'LIKE', '%'.'2017-04-12'.'%')`

```
$filtered_table = Method::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'methods.created_by')
      ->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'users.role_id')
      ->leftJoin('types', 'types.id', '=', 'methods.type_id')
      //->where($request->filters)//will act as a searchmap
      ->where('created_at', 'LIKE', '%'.'2017-04-12'.'%')
      ->get([ 'users.username', 'users.id AS users_id', 'methods.*', 'methods.id AS method_id', 'methods.name AS method_name', 'roles.id AS role_id', 'roles.name AS role_name',
      'types.id AS type_id_typetable', 'types.name AS type_name']);
```

My question is what's the proper way of using 'LIKE' because I can't get any values from it. The reason I am using it is that because that column has other string to it. See this picture.

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to only read/or find '2017-04-12' in that column(I am doing this for testing purposes).

Comment: you didn't mention which created_at ? it can be roles.created_at or types.created_at or method.created_at

Comment: methods.created_at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Eloquent, I'd recommend you to use `whereDate()` instead:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2017-04-12')->toDateString();
....
->whereDate('created_at', $date)
```

If you don't have Carbon object, you can just use string:

```
->whereDate('created_at', '2017-04-12')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like:

Method1 using Raw query:

```
$q->where(DB::raw("DATE(created_at) = '".date('Y-m-d')."'"));
```

Method 2 by `whereDate`:

```
$q->whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'));
```

For  more details visit:

http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/